# Position in Vector using STL

Tags: c++, stl

im trying to locate the position of the minimum value in a vector, using STL find algorithm (and the min_element algorithm), but instead of returning the postion, its just giving me the value. E.g, if the minimum value is it, is position will be returned as 8 etc. What am I doing wrong here?

```
int value = *min_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());
cout << "min value at position " << *find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), value);
```

Comment: There is a typo in your question: you say you want to find the *maximum* value in a vector, while you're obviously trying to find the *minimum* value.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`min_element` already gives you the iterator, no need to invoke `find` (additionally, it's inefficient because it's twice the work). Use `distance` or the `-` operator:

```
cout << "min value at " << min_element(v2.begin(), v2.end()) - v2.begin();
```

Comment: I TRIED THE SAME WITH LIST, BLEW MY HEAD OFF! WHY?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Because you are using caps lock (and because you didn’t read my answer carefully – try `std::distance`).

Comment: Aha, sorry. When I thought about why its so, I realized  I will have to stick to the `-` operator as I'm assuming that the distance operator is operating on linked lists and will have a time complexity of `O(n)`. Bless C++ STL for not implementing `-` on linked lists, saving people a lot of time.

Answer (score 15):

Both algorithms you're using return iterators. If you dereference an iterator, you get the object which is "pointed" by this iterator, which is why you print the *value* and not the *position* when doing

> ```
> cout << "min value at position " << *find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), value);
> ```

An iterator can be seen as a pointer (well, not exactly, but let's say so for the sake of simplicity); therefore, an iterator alone can't give you the position in the container. Since you're iterating a vector, you can use the minus operator, as Konrad said:

> ```
> cout << "min value at " << min_element(v2.begin(), v2.end()) - v2.begin();
> ```

but I would recommend using the std::distance algorithm, which is much more flexible and will work on all standard containers:

> ```
> cout << "min value at " << distance(v2.begin(), min_element(v2.begin(), v2.end()));
> ```

Comment: using the distance would be the correct way to do it. I once encoutered a problem using the `operator-`, after a lot of resizing the return value using the operator was different from the actual position.

Comment: @Florian: Can you elaborate on the issue you had with `operator-`? As far as I know, `distance` is specialized for random access iterators (like the ones provided by `vector`) to use `-`, so it surprises me that they could give different results. Are you sure you were using a `vector`?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer to what you think you asked with "How do I determine position in `std::vector<>` given an iterator from it?" is the function `std::distance`.

What you probably meant to do, however, was to get the value for the iterator, which you get by dereferencing it:

```
using namespace std;
vector<int>::const_iterator it = min_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());
cout << "min value at position " << distance(v2.begin(), it) << " is " << *it;
```